# How do I POST using Ajax a form from a sub-domain to home domain without triggering CORS?

Tags: jquery, ajax, post, cors

I'm trying to set up a form on a subdomain (ex. sub.mysite.com) which posts data to my main website (mysite.com), but I'm running foul of CORS.

I've tried, as recommended from some Googling, setting document.domain but this doesn't seem to help. As I understand it, I cannot use Jsonp because it's for reading, not posting?

Code so far:

```
<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" id="form" action="mysite.com/form-here">
  <input type="text" name="firstname">
  <input type="text" name="lastname">
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

```
$("#form").submit(function(event){
    document.domain = "mysite.com";
    event.preventDefault(); 
    var post_url = $(this).attr("action");
    var request_method = $(this).attr("method");
    var form_data = $(this).serialize();

    $.ajax({
        url : post_url,
        type: request_method,
        data : form_data
    })
});
```

Comment: without CORS not possible, [Same-origin policy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same-origin_policy)

Answer (score 0):

If you're running both domains, you could set properly `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` ([see doc](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Access-Control-Allow-Origin)) or your main domain to allow at least `sub.mysite.com` or the wildcard `*`.

`$.ajax` will automatically make the `OPTIONS` preflight call and then will make the `POST` one.